# Search result scrolling / paging on Android Market?

Tags: google-play-store

I am confused: if I use search on the Market app on Android 2.2, it tells me often that there are hundreds or even thousands of matches, but shows exactly 10, no more. Is there a way to scroll / page / whatever that I've overlooked? 8-}

Comment: What device are you using?  What Matt says is correct, but for instance, my rooted NookColor I have to rotate landscape in order for the paging to work.

Comment: It seems this really was a bug: after updating Android it just works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll to thr bottom of the list it should automatically load more results. Mine sometimes gets hung up and shows the "thinking" symbol for a few seconds, but then loads more.

Comment: That's what I expected, but what usually does not happen. Probably a bug. :-{

Answer (score 0):

[Based on your question here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5128/how-to-switch-keyboard-layout-for-external-keyboard), I see you're using a tablet.  You may need to rotate your device to landscape mode in order for the paging in the Market to work correctly.  I have to do this with my rooted Nook Color.