# Setting an external keyboard to the Colemak layout

Tags: external-keyboard, input-methods

I have found soft keyboard applications that provide the Colemak layout for the virtual keyboard. However, I need the layout when touch-typing on a physical keyboard.

In my case, I'm using a regular USB keyboard plugged into an Iconia A500 tablet. The keymap should be freely customizable by modifying system files, but I'd prefer to do this without rooting.

How can I remap the keys of a physical keyboard to the Colemak layout?

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5128/how-to-switch-keyboard-layout-for-external-keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the [External Keyboard Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo) app lets me switch layouts of an external USB keyboard on my Nexus 7, no root access needed.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this app! I'm currently use an Apple Wireless Keyboard on my Android device. And that External Keyboard Helper app allows me to remap the useless upper-right `Eject CD` to `Del`. Tips: when trying to setup this, the Del key can be chosen by a key name "Forward Delete".

Answer (score 0):

According to the first Android related link on the front page of http://colemak.com/ the [AnySoftKeyboard app](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/) ([market link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard)) is their main recommendation for Android phones. One of the bullet points in the featuireslist on their home page is:

> Physical keyboard is supported
>   as-well.

It sounds like that could do the job for you?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. My external USB keyboard still has US QWERTY layout when I am using Colemak AnySoftKeyboard.

Comment: I can confirm that ASK doesn't work for physical keyboards. They have an issue open in their bugtracker: http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/issues/detail?id=181

Answer (score 0):

I have [a similar issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13118/can-i-use-dvorak-on-a-physical-keyboard) trying to get my physical keyboard to work with Dvorak. I came across the following links:

http://www.mjvanderwielen.com/?p=1321
http://jahrome.free.fr/index.php/keyboard-mapping-android-htc-desire?lang=en

These essentially describe how to create your own keyboard mapping file. You'd need root access to do this. I haven't tried this myself though (yet.)

Answer (score 0):

<s>As a partial solution...</s>

I've had some success with [**extkeyboardremapper**](http://code.google.com/p/extkeyboardremapper/) (AKA **laurent2o1o Keyboard**). I successfully swapped <kbd>Q</kbd> with <kbd>A</kbd> by following the [translated French instructions](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.archoslounge.net%2Fforum%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D20319).

I haven't got as far as creating a full layout, but I wonder if I could just copy layouts from somewhere in Ubuntu.

Edit: On Ubuntu and probably most other Linux systems, these files are found in:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

For non-Linux users, here's the web repo of the source:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/tree/symbols?h=2.2-branch

The files aren't directly compatible with extkeyboardremapper, but they can serve as a guide for making the `k2g.cfg` file. Colemak and Dvorak can be found in the `us` file, other files such as `gb` just amend the US version it seems.

Edit: Using the X11 keyboard layout files as a guide, I made a `k2g.cfg` for Colemak, to complete my solution.

Here's how to use it:

```
mkdir /sdcard/keyremap
```

Make this file:

`/sdcard/keyremap/s2k.cfg`

```
86 => 773
```

This is because Android doesn't seem to have a keycode for `<LSGT>`, so let's call it `773` for now.

Make this file:

`/sdcard/keyremap/k2g.cfg`

```
==== USA - Colemak ====

0 68 ` ~ 0303 ~
0 8 1 ! ¡ ¹
0 9 2 @ º ²
0 10 3 # ª ³
0 11 4 $ ¢ £
0 12 5 % € ¥
0 13 6 ^ ħ Ħ
0 14 7 & ð Ð
0 15 8 * þ Þ
0 16 9 ( ‘ “
0 17 0 ) ’ ”
0 69 - _ – —
0 70 = + × ÷

0 45 q Q ä Ä
0 51 w W å Å
33 f F ã Ã
46 p P ø Ø
48 g G 0328 ~
53 j J đ Đ
49 l L ł Ł
37 u U ú Ú
43 y Y ü Ü
44 ; : ö Ö
0 71 [ { « ‹
0 72 ] } » ›
0 73 \ | ~ ~

0 29 a A á Á
47 r R 0300 ~
32 s S ß ~
34 t T 0301 030B
35 d D 0308 ~
0 36 h H 030C ~
38 n N ñ Ñ
39 e E é É
40 i I í Í
74 o O ó Ó
0 75 ' " õ Õ

0 54 z Z æ Æ
0 52 x X 0302 ~
0 31 c C ç Ç
0 50 v V œ Œ
0 30 b B 0306 ~
42 k K 030A ~
0 41 m M 0304 ~
0 55 , < 0327 ~
0 56 . > 0307 ~
0 76 / ? ¿ ~

0 773 - _ – —
0 62 0020 0020 0020 00A0


==== United Kingdom - Colemak (extension) ====

9 2 " ² ⅛
10 3 £ ³ £
11 4 $ € ¼

75 ' @ 0302 030C
68 ` ¬ | |

73 # ~ 0300 0306
773 \ | | ¦
```

The prepended `0`'s effectively comment out the line. I've commented out all but the necessary lines due to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/extkeyboardremapper/issues/detail?id=15), but if the bug gets fixed, or you use the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> characters more than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcuts, then just uncomment them.

US users can cut the UK extension at the end, others will have to replace it with their own.

If you really want to duplicate your <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, you need to add this line to `s2k.cfg`:

```
58 => 67
```

...but you may find that the backspace function is merely added to the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key.

Now just install **extkeyboardremapper**, enable it, and select it!

Comment: Just discovered a bug that [CapsLock doesn't work for mapped keys](http://code.google.com/p/extkeyboardremapper/issues/detail?id=17).

Comment: I have the same problem with External Keyboard Helper: I just can't manage to make Caps Lock another Control. Although I can choose it in the custom layout, it simply doesn't seem to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Android 4.1 has built-in support for changing the layout of USB and Bluetooth keyboards, /and/ allows users to install custom layouts without root.

Not much use for devices without Jellybean, but it's good to know that up-to-date devices don't have this issue anymore.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17119