# How can I set my external keyboard to use a Dvorak layout?

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard

Tested in Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9 and Samsung Galaxy S4 in >= Android 5.0.1 with Logitech Bluetooth keyboard and Apple Wireless keybord 3rd generation without rooting the phone and without external applications. Also tested in the CyanogenMod versions of the corresponding Androids.

I found a bug in Android main system's Dvorak in Lollipop >= 5.0.1, 11.1.2016. 
Connect Bluetooth keyboard to your system. Choose some keyboard Dvorak. Go to SMS. Double tap Space and Select English US Dvorak. Type with your Wireless keyboard (I use Apple Wireless keyboard 3rd gen). It types Qwerty put shows physically Dvorak in the screen. This is a bug in Android, which bug report is [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198665&thanks=198665&ts=1452540328) with the issue number 198665.

---

How can I set my external keyboard to use a Dvorak layout without hacks?

Comment: I doubt you can, those files aren't editable without root and [Android doesn't support it yet](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17119).

Comment: Not sure if its a duplicate, but this sounds very similar to this previous question [How to switch keyboard layout for external keyboard](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5128/how-to-switch-keyboard-layout-for-external-keyboard) although that is a localization as well as layout change, and you're presumably keeping the same language, but changing layout.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [External Keyboard Helper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper) to do it. No need for rooting. From version 2.7, the app supports Dvorak out-of-the-box.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the developer of this app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Root Explorer to change the keyboard layout file in `/system/usr/keylayout/`

For the details, [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1336114) explains it well.

Answer (score 2):

This can be set by the "Language and Input" menu in the "Physical Keyboard" sub-section.

Touch the name of your paired keyboard, and touch the "Set Keyboard Type" button. Scroll down to "English (US), Dvorak Style" and touch it.

Comment: Sorry. This answer is buggy. I tested it. Connect Bluetooth keyboard to your system. Choose some keyboard Dvorak. Go to SMS. Double tap Space and Select English US Dvorak. Type with your Wireless keyboard (I use Apple Wireless keyboard 3rd gen). It types Qwerty put shows physically Dvorak in the screen. This is a bug in Android!